# I installed tcpdump, but it is showing command not found while using it

Tags: command-line, package-management, kali-linux, tcpdump

[image: The Image contains the following lines i used]

Also I used `whereis` & `which` command to check if the package exists 
and it does exist.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, [don't attach screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is often difficult to read and the post won't be found by others googling for the same problem. Also, any contributor trying to help will have to type-copy commands you used in order to reproduce the problem. Please edit your post, and copy-and-paste the console output with appropriate "code" formatting.

Comment: Please update question with output of `type -a tcpdump` and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: I found the solution, actual it was a $PATH problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is installed to `/usr/sbin/tcpdump`, since `tcpdump` is supposed to run as root user or with equivalent privilege.

To verify that, you can use `dpkg -L` to show where the installed files are located on disk:

```
$ dpkg -L tcpdump
/.
/etc
/etc/apparmor.d
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump
/usr
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/tcpdump                         <- Here it is !
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tcpdump
...
```

So, you can either

1. run it with `sudo tcpdump` as a normal user, or
2. switch to root user first, then run `tcpdump`, or
3. add `/usr/sbin` to your `PATH` environment variable